# Break statement doesn't work. It returns the answer 50 twice. Is there a way to break out once the condition is true and printed the first time?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, break

This code works, but it returns the answer 15 twice. Is there a way to break out once it's been met the first time?

```
let input = "2 3 4 4 4 5 6 10 8";

let nums = input.split(" ").map(x => parseInt(x));

for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
  let first = nums[i];

  for(let j = 0; j < nums.length; j++){
    let second = nums[j];
    if(first + second === 15){
        console.log(first * second);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `break` ? Or, if in a function, `return`?

Comment: Also, is there some reason you are starting with a string and turning that into an array instead of just starting with an array `let input = [2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 10, 8];`?

Comment: Here's a hint: you are using 2 loops, and `break` statement only break out one loop. How do you break the other loop? :)